# Is there any way to connect to Microsoft Project Server via a C# Application?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-project, project-server

What would you do if you had to write a C# Application which would need to borrow Tasks and Projects from Microsoft Project?

The purpose is writing a C# Application which complements several features of Microsoft Project. For example I want my application to print certain types of customized reports based on data from Microsoft Project.

Comment: I would read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153593/programmatically-access-a-microsoft-project-mpp-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you. That helps a bit! Unfortunately, the question is related to the "offline" version of MP. I am interested in accessing it via its Server / Database rather than the Project File (which would require somebody perpetually saving it every time a change is made).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project Server exposes it's own API: the [Project Server Interface (PSI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457477.aspx), which would probably be your first port of call. If this doesn't suit your purpose, [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) offers an interface which should allow you to read data from the Project Server database directly... although I'd caution that I haven't tried this myself yet!

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!