# Integrate Project 2010 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-project

Are there ways to integrate MS Project 2010 to SharePoint portal, except making PWA site in SharePoint farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow theses steps

1. In Project, click the File tab to open the Backstage view. Click Save & Send
2. Click Sync with Tasks Lists.
3. In the Site URL list, select the URL name of the SharePoint site that contains the list that you want to sync to.
4. Click Validate URL.
5. In the Select an existing tasks list list, select the name of the SharePoint task list to which you want the project tasks list to sync.
6. If you want to sync the Project task list with a new list in SharePoint, type a new name. A new task list will be created in SharePoint, and will become synced up with the one in Project.
7. Click Sync.

Note : At this point, don’t use a URL that contains the name of the task list you want to use.

Comment: But can I syncronize projects in SharePoint with Project Server? And it'll be fine to do it programmatically, not by user.

Comment: it all depends on your use case

Comment: Maybe I asked question not exactly. I have SharePoint portal and Project server. Can I interact with Project documents on server without making PWA site in farm? Maybe, with the help of WebPart on my Sharepoint site?

Comment: You have link about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153593/programmatically-access-a-microsoft-project-mpp-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: You can use SharePoint's BCS to read data from Project Server and put it to SharePoint lists, you can use Project to Sharepoint list synchronization, you can develop your own synchronization using PSI and SharePoint API. Your need will finally define the technologies to use.